# Merging multiple dataframe columns into one using for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

Below is the script that I am using

```
dfs = [df2,df3,df4,df5,df6]
for i in dfs:
    df_merge = pd.merge(df1,i,how='left',on='Date')
print("Shape of df_merge = ",df_merge.shape)
```

Let us assume the shape of each individual dataframes is (100,2). 'Date' is the common column in all. After using above script and printing I am getting a shape of (100,3) i.e only df6 is getting merged with df1. I need to merge all in one. Any suggestion will be appreciated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you save every thing in df_merge. df_merge is always the latest merged, not the sum of all merged dataframes.

I would suggest to set df_merge to a value first, like this.

```py
dfs = [df2,df3,df4,df5,df6]
df_merge = df1
for i in dfs:
    df_merge = pd.merge(df_merge,i,how='left',on='Date')
print("Shape of df_merge = ",df_merge.shape)
```